# Would a 1 lb refrigerant loss result in icing?

Tags: hvac

Just had a new unit installed in my home about three weeks ago. When I got home yesterday it wasn’t cooling properly but everything was running. HVAC technician came out and said he found a block of ice over the evaporator coils. They sent another technician out this morning after the ice thawed to check the system for leaks. They said the unit was 1lb low of refrigerant and found a leak in the liquid line connection at the coils so they tightened the connection. Is a 1 lb loss really enough to cause a torso sized block of ice??

Comment: presumably depends whether the unit has 3 lbs or 300 lbs of refrigerant to start with, but certainly refrigerant loss can cause freeze-up. And home-sized units don't have 300 lbs... One hopes they repaired this (their installation error) for free...

Answer (score 5):

Yes a 1 lb loss on a modern (small) system is enough to cause a problem, the newer high efficiency heat pumps or mini splits have less in them than old school, I used to say 30% was the point where ice ups occur but some systems using the pre-charge in the compressor to connect a line set at the max length it could be much less as the system may only have 4 or 5 lbs so any loss puts it on edge and a full pound is a lot in that case.

Comment: Is that 1 lb. by weight or by pressure?

Comment: Refrigerant is measured by weight, pressure is almost meaningless without temps.

Comment: Are you sure you're not an HVAC guy? lol So what do you think of those DIY systems where they overfill the compressor, and you DIY-plumb the line-set and draw vacuum, pressurize with nitrogen for leak testing and draw vacuum again, before finally opening the valve and letting the refrigerant out of the compressor into the line-set/indoor unit...

Comment: Sounds like a topic for [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=diy.stackexchange.com) @Harper-ReinstateUkraine! ;)

Comment: @harper almost all systems are shipped with the required charge. I do have a universal 608 license and a 609. I posted about the diy systems when I found out about them if checked for leaks after installing they meet the regulations and can be DIY.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so.  I thought the nitrogen charge was a clever way to avoid freon handling.

Comment: Nominally charged for a line set that's 15'~25'. Any shorter or longer than that and it's decidedly under or over.

Answer (score -2):

My little over 1 year old 18k heat pump was icing.  Leak on smaller liquid line at outdoor connection.

Was not putting out heat that you could feel and bottom 1/4 coils iced up when about 40 deg f outside.

Turn on to cool, put a gage on it, closed liquid line valve.  Watched gauge until it just started to go 0 psi.  Closed other valve quick and pulled disconnect.  Just about empty in air handler side now.

Little 1/4 inch liquid lines needs an extra .050 sticking out of flare fitting and only 12ft lb of torque to tighten and refrigersnt oil to lube fitting and threads.

Evacuated all lines and all lines on test gahge lines.  Used bathroom scale on 25lb tank.  Filled with tank upright vapor.  Sprayed fitting with windex, no bubbles. Opened valves to outddor unit.

Took about 5 minutes of running on A/C mode to fill. Let the vspir gobin a minute or so, thrn put backn9n scale.  Did thst 5 or 6 times. Dry full is 47oz of refrigerant.  I put in about 20oz.  About 45 deg F outside and 70 inside.  Gauge would increase only 10 psi when I was adding when i was wgat seemed full. Liquid filling is with tank upside down. You can hydrolock a compressor if done wrong. BAD BAD BAD.

When on heat, your test Port is the high pressure side now.  Cant think of a simple way to fill like that.

If you system is empty, you could have air in machine.  Mine got caght right away, so wasnt worried.

Short story long.  About 40% low on 18k machine.  Didnt work and needed 1 25 lbs to work ok again.  Not quite low yet to blow error code.  Probably real close.

Hard to be confident machibe is back to 100% filled without removing and weighing charge.  Thats pricey equipment that you probably cant rent either.

Seeing it feed less refrigerant in machine is kinda an art.  Better to be a little low than too high.  You can add more later if needed.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Things work a bit differently here, so please take the [tour] and read up on [how to write a good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), then feel free to [edit] this to answer the question asked.

Comment: Not sure how you got the refrigerant or what was being used but most all refrigerants require a liquid fill . 

using gas only you do not get a proper mix of the stuff in the tank one of the things that is covered in training, I won’t down vote as not sure but there is a lot missing and in the US top can get up to a 25000.00$ fine , so be careful I had a firend that was turned in by neighbor he had a license but not the right one, he now has a basic 608 and 609 the judge tossed it since he got the second one prior to going to court.